# NoSQL VS RDB for followers/following

Tags: mysql, database, nosql

I want to ask a good approach to select a good database type and design schema for followers/following. RDB such as MySQL will be used to store users records and I need to decide how to design database schema for followers/following and which database I need to use among RDB and NoSQL.

When I refer to an answer in similar question, relation table where User_Id and Follower_Id is stored is recommended: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19734232

Relation table schema in RDB is very standard approach for this but I still have question if we have issues such as performance degrading as the relation pairs are increased so much in that table. And I want to ask if NoSQL will have more advantages than RDB to handle followers/following.